# Adding special character to the END of SINGLE and DOUBLE line strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need to ADD special character '♪' to the END of SINGLE and DOUBLE line strings

Below is the BEFORE and AFTER of the results I'm trying to achieve.

Assume this will be done with two separate find/replace inputs.

At the bottom you will find my feeble regex attempts using NotePad++.

```
==============================
BEFORE
==============================
400
00:31:44,633 --> 00:31:45,716
Come on.

401
00:31:59,940 --> 00:32:02,399
Caleb used to do that
when he ate.

402
00:32:03,902 --> 00:32:05,069
Pull my hair like that.

410
00:32:46,653 --> 00:32:48,654
♪ Saying</i>

411
00:32:48,738 --> 00:32:52,241
♪ This is my message to you</i>

412
00:32:56,163 --> 00:32:57,538
♪ Don't worry</i>

636
00:55:59,545 --> 00:56:02,296
♪ You don't own me

637
00:56:02,798 --> 00:56:06,676
♪ I'm not just
one of your many toys

638
00:56:06,969 --> 00:56:09,929
♪ You don't own me

639
00:56:10,347 --> 00:56:16,394
♪ Don't say
I can't go with other boys

640
00:56:16,728 --> 00:56:20,106
♪ And don't tell me
what to do

641
00:56:20,816 --> 00:56:24,026
♪ Don't tell me what to say ♪

642
00:56:24,278 --> 00:56:27,822
♪ And please,
when I go out with you ♪

643
00:56:28,365 --> 00:56:31,742
♪ Don't put me on display ♪

644
00:56:31,952 --> 00:56:36,080
♪ 'Cause you don't own me ♪

==============================
AFTER
==============================
400
00:31:44,633 --> 00:31:45,716
Come on.

401
00:31:59,940 --> 00:32:02,399
Caleb used to do that
when he ate.

402
00:32:03,902 --> 00:32:05,069
Pull my hair like that.

410
00:32:46,653 --> 00:32:48,654
♪ Saying</i> ♪

411
00:32:48,738 --> 00:32:52,241
♪ This is my message to you</i> ♪

412
00:32:56,163 --> 00:32:57,538
♪ Don't worry</i> ♪

636
00:55:59,545 --> 00:56:02,296
♪ You don't own me ♪

637
00:56:02,798 --> 00:56:06,676
♪ I'm not just
one of your many toys ♪

638
00:56:06,969 --> 00:56:09,929
♪ You don't own me ♪

639
00:56:10,347 --> 00:56:16,394
♪ Don't say
I can't go with other boys ♪

640
00:56:16,728 --> 00:56:20,106
♪ And don't tell me
what to do ♪

641
00:56:20,816 --> 00:56:24,026
♪ Don't tell me what to say ♪

642
00:56:24,278 --> 00:56:27,822
♪ And please,
when I go out with you ♪

643
00:56:28,365 --> 00:56:31,742
♪ Don't put me on display ♪

644
00:56:31,952 --> 00:56:36,080
♪ 'Cause you don't own me ♪
```

### Add Music Note to END of SINGLE LINE STRING:

```
Find:   (?=♪\B)(.*)
Replace: $1 ♪
```

### Add Music Note to END of DOUBLE LINE STRING:

```
Find:   (?=♪)(.*)\r\n([A-Za-z]+?)
Replace: $1\r\n$2 ♪
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is `♪` appearing only after `</i>` now? Wasn't it earlier showing after every 2nd line?

Comment: Some of the existing entries have the '</i>' . Just have the ♪ go in after the  '</i>' os that it looks something like a have shown in the AFTER section. I can easily search for  '</i> ♪' and replace with ' ♪'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option might be using:

```
^(♪\h+[A-Za-z].*?(?:\R[A-Za-z].*?)?)♪?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `♪\h+[A-Za-z]` Match ♪, 1+ spaces, a char A-Za-z
  - `.*?` Match any char as least as possible
  - `(?:\R[A-Za-z].*?)?` Optionally match the next line if it starts with A-Za-z
- `)` Close group 1
- `♪?` Match an optional ♪
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Wg0hc/1)

In the replacement use:

```
$1 ♪
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single search/replace.

Use this regex for search:

```bash
^(?:♪ )?([A-Z].*?)(?: ♪)?$(?:(\n.+?)(?: ♪)?$)?
```

Replace it with:

```
♪ $1$2 ♪
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ydpX2e/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:♪ )?`: Match `♪`  as an optional match
- `([A-Z].*?)`: Match an uppercase character followed by any text till end of line in capture group #1
- `(?: ♪)?$`: Match  `♪` as an optional match before line end
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(\n.+?)`: Match line break followed by 1+ of any char till end of line in capture group #2
  - `(?: ♪)?$`: Match  `♪` as an optional match before line end
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this *optional*
- `♪ $1$2 ♪` is replacement that wraps our matches with `♪`

Comment: Did you try this in Notepad++ ? It a appears to add the  ♪ characters to ALL strings even if they don't start with  ♪

Comment: Answer has been updated. It should work on NP++ same as this demo

Comment: Added 400 to 402 that have NO '♪' at beginning of line string. 400 to 402 are having the '♪' added to beginning and end of strings. Plus the double line strings are getting the '♪' at end of the first line AND at beginning of second line. Not a big deal as I could. fix after. The biggest issue is it ADDING '♪' to 400 to 402 where NO '♪' exists at beginning of string.

Comment: Plus it does NOT add a  '♪' to the end of the SECOND line, only adds  '♪' to END of first line. As in the case of 639 where the  '♪' are already correct, it adds the  '♪' to the beginning  and end of second line. It should pass over 639 as 639 is already correct. Please try it in Notepad++

Comment: Is this final edit to question or you can change it again?

Comment: Yes, final edit. The only lines that should get modified are 410 thru  640. The others should not be touched by the regex find. Your help is VERY MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(♪.*?)(?=(?:\R^$)|\z)/$1 ♪/gms

    ^    ^     ^                   the regex
                        ^  ^       replacement
                              ^    flags
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhoevZ/1)

With the edit (where it seems some of the entries already have the ending note) you can modify the regex to be:

```
/^(♪[^♪]*?)(?=(?:\R\R)|\z)/$1 ♪/gm
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QvVb0x/1)

Comment: Tried both in Notepad++ returns with "Can't find"?